# How to save changes of courses in EmployeeCourse table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

**What i Need**

I need to save changes in courses in EmployeeCourse table

by remove all course for employee from EmployeeCourse table

then add courses after changes

**Problem**

**when add changes in courses after remove i get error in save changes() function**

{"An error occurred while updating the entries.

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

\"FK_EmployeeCourse_Course\". The conflict occurred in database \"mycourse\",

table \"dbo.Course\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

under submit button edit [httppost]

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditEmployeeVm model)
        {
var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);
// remove all courses
                foreach (EmployeeCourse eec in emp.EmployeeCourses.ToList())
                {
                    var ec = db.EmployeeCourses.Find(eec.Id);
                    db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
                }
// add courses again
                foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
                {
                    db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });

                }
                db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Debug result**

debug add as image below

[image: add courses error]

**Details**

Relation between two tables one to many

EmployeeCourse

Id(primary key)   CourseId(forign key)  EmployeeId(forign key)

Course table in database

Id(pk)      CourseName

```
I using following view model for edit to get CourseIds 

@model StudentCourses.Models.EditEmployeeVm

    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".course-item").remove();

        });
        $('#AvailableCourses').change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var text = $("#AvailableCourses option:selected").text();
            var existingCourses = $("input[name='CourseIds']")
                .map(function () { return this.value; }).get();

            if (existingCourses.indexOf(val) === -1) {

                var newItem = $("<div/>").addClass("course-item")
          .append(text + ' <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="' + val + '">Remove </a>');
                newItem.append('<input type="text" name="CourseIds" value="' + val + '" />');

                $("#items").append(newItem);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

to retrieve courses from database in edit view i used code below

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.HiddenFor(g => g.Id)
        @Html.LabelFor(f => f.Name)
        @Html.DropDownList("AvailableCourses", Model.Courses, "Select")
        <h4>Existing courses</h4>
        <div id="items"></div>
        foreach (var c in Model.ExistingCourses)
        {
            <div class="course-item">
                @c.Name <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="@c.Id">Remove </a>
                <input type="text" name="CourseIds" value="@c.Id" />
            </div>
        }

    }
</div>
```

model used for that as following

```
    public class EditEmployeeVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Courses { get; set; }
        public int[] CourseIds { set; get; }
        public List<CourseVm> ExistingCourses { set; get; }
    }
    public class CourseVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

**update**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var vm = new EditEmployeeVm { Id = id };
            var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
            vm.Name = emp.Name;
            vm.ExistingCourses = db.EmployeeCourses
                                    .Where(g => g.EmployeeId == id)
                                    .Select(f => new CourseVm
                                    {
                                        Id = f.Id,
                                        Name = f.Course.CourseName
                                    }).ToList();
            vm.CourseIds = vm.ExistingCourses.Select(g => g.Id).ToArray();
            vm.Courses = db.Courses.Select(f => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                Text = f.CourseName
            }).ToList();

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Comment: Is 461 a valid courseId in `Course` table ?

Comment: sorry i confuse 461 is not valid in course table

Comment: course table have two values 1 python 2 delphi

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: So you are sending wrong values from your form. You probably need to fix the place where you are getting the value 461. Make sure you are getting the Id from course table.

Comment: so that what i do

Comment: how to get id from course table if possible

Comment: Show us the code of your get action where you load the AvailableCourses property

Comment: in update section above i add code for edit view get action

Answer (score 0):

In your EDIT Get action, You are using the wrong id for CourseVm. It should be the Course Id, but you are setting the `EmployeeCourse` record/entity Id.

This should fix it.

```
vm.ExistingCourses = db.EmployeeCourses.Where(g => g.EmployeeId == id)
                                       .Select(f => new CourseVm
                                           {
                                              Id = f.Course.Id,
                                              Name = f.Course.CourseName
                                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you very much it solved but remaining one point not solved if possible when remove all course then click submit it give me exception error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in this line foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)